# How do I open the app drawer from the home screen when the toolbar is activated?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-s8

In a Samsung Galaxy Tab S8, with the latest update, there's now a toolbar that you can turn on and off. With the toolbar off, you can swipe from the bottom of the screen to open the app drawer. With the toolbar on that swipe gesture no longer works. How do you open it? When an app is open, there's a 9 dot menu on the bottom left, but when you are in the home, there's no menu.

Comment: You should add an (annotated) screen shot, otherwise it is hard to understand what you are talking about.